# How can I sort a dictionary by key in Scala?

Tags: scala, sorting, hashmap

It is easy to sort a Map by keys or values in Python ([this question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)).

I would like to do the same thing in Scala, lets say I have a dictionary like:

```
val A= Map(0 -> 1.0, 3 -> 5.0,2->7.0)
```

I would like to get a List of tuples that correspond to the sorted Map by keys:

```
val A_sorted= List((0,1.0),(2,7.0),(3,5.0))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Map(0 -> 1.0, 3 -> 5.0,2->7.0).toList.sortBy(_._1)

res1: List[(Int, Double)] = List((0,1.0), (2,7.0), (3,5.0))
```

Answer (score 6):

It suffices to

```
A.toList.sorted
```

In sorting duples, the first coordinate is sorted first; on equality the second coordinate is used.

To note that in Scala labels with first letter in uppercase by convention denote types (or classes).

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the :_* syntax to output the contents of a Sequence and then to
convert your map to a sortedMap:

```
val a = Map(0 -> 1.0, 3 -> 5.0,2->7.0)

val sortedA = scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap(a.toList:_*)
```

You can convert it to a list if needed:

```
sortedA.toList
```